# Perl XML::LibXML Partial Match

Tags: perl

How to tell XML::LibXML to find nodes in a xml file by partial match, e.g. if the node  contains 'Disc' or 'iso'.

```
(@discs) = $link->findnodes("./link[./description/text()='Disc.iso']");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the XPath function [`contains`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains). Combine the expressions with the function [`or`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans).